# php regular expression help needed on special charecters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

here goes my **code**

```
    $string="According to a report on the Times of In#dia, &#8220 Telan#gana Rashtra Samiti chief K Chandrasekhar #Rao has seen a #sinister motive behind the protests against the formation of Telangana";
preg_match_all('/(?!\b)(#\w+\b)/' ,$string, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $match){
$string = str_replace("$match","[h]".$match."[/h]",$string);

}

echo $string;
```

**output**

> According to a report on the Times of In#dia, &[h]#8220[/h] Telan#gana
>   Rashtra Samiti chief K Chandrasekhar [h]#Rao[/h] has seen a
>   [h]#sinister[/h] motive behind the protests against the formation of
>   Telangana

i want to replace only the string starts with `#` but it also replacing `&#8220` to `&[h]#8220[/h]`  . please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a positive lookbehind since there's always a word boundary before a hash `#` :

```
/(?<=\s|^)(#\w+\b)/
```

Which makes sure there's either a space or the beginning of the string before the hashed word.

You can use this in a `preg_replace`:

```
$string="According to a report on the Times of In#dia, &#8220 Telan#gana Rashtra Samiti chief K Chandrasekhar #Rao has seen a #sinister motive behind the protests against the formation of Telangana";
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=\s|^)(#\w+\b)/', "[h]$1[/h]", $string);
```

Comment: output is same as - According to a report on the Times of In[h]#dia[/h], &[h]#8220[/h] Telan[h]#gana[/h] Rashtra Samiti chief K Chandrasekhar #Rao has seen a #sinister motive behind the protests against the formation of Telangana

Comment: O/p According to a report on the Times of In#dia, “ Telan#gana Rashtra Samiti chief K Chandrasekhar [h]#Rao[/h] has seen a [h]#sinister[/h] motive behind the protests against the formation of Telangana    - its removing "&#8220" and placing "

Comment: @Jeery small request .. can we remove '#' inside of that [h]#Rao[/h]

Comment: #sinister become [h]sinister[/h]

Comment: please check this - [codepad](http://codepad.org/DEeHjEIh)  - i placed  special characters before #, our expression not detecting, please go through the demo. help me on this @Jerry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38944/discussion-between-devendar-and-jerry)